# powershell - How to send outlook mail with content read from excel (csv)

Tags: excel, powershell, email

can anyone give me an example about how to How to send outlook mail with content read from excel (csv)?

It seems to work for txt but not for excel

```
$o = New-Object -com Outlook.Application
$mail = $o.CreateItem(0)
$yesterday = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString('MMM dd, yyyy')

$mail.subject = "Missing/Empty Files"

$mail.Attachments.Add("I:\BadFileReport_20170711_0103.csv")

$mail.HTMLBody += "<span style='font-family:Courier New;font-size:12pt'>"  

$mail.HTMLbody = $mail.HTMLBody + "<B>Please check missing/empty files for yesterday</B><br><br>" 

$file1 = import-csv I:\BadFileReport_20170711_0103.csv


foreach ($line in $file1)
{
    $mail.HTMLbody = $mail.HTMLbody  + $line   
}

$mail.HTMLbody = $mail.HTMLbody + $title2 + "<br>"




$signature = "<br>Regards,<br>"

$mail.HTMLbody = $mail.HTMLbody + $signature



$mail.To = "12345@imcnam.ssmb.com"

write-host "mail sent"

$mail.save()
```

output looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You import the CSV file, now you just need to use the `ConvertTo-HTML` cmdlet to make it Outlook friendly.

```
$o = New-Object -com Outlook.Application
$mail = $o.CreateItem(0)
$yesterday = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString('MMM dd, yyyy')

$mail.subject = "Missing/Empty Files"

$mail.Attachments.Add("I:\BadFileReport_20170711_0103.csv")

$mail.HTMLBody += "<span style='font-family:Courier New;font-size:12pt'>"  

$mail.HTMLbody = $mail.HTMLBody + "<B>Please check missing/empty files for yesterday</B><br><br>" 

$mail.HTMLbody = $mail.HTMLBody + = import-csv I:\BadFileReport_20170711_0103.csv | ConvertTo-HTML -as Table -Property * -Fragment

$signature = "<br>Regards,<br>"

$mail.HTMLbody = $mail.HTMLbody + $signature

$mail.To = "12345@imcnam.ssmb.com"

write-host "mail sent"

$mail.save()
```

Comment: thanks it works perfect. i'm wondering why i was not able to find this simple command when i googled everywhere.